# Problemas al alinear elementos en linea

Tags: html, css, html5, css3

Tengo el siguiente código:

```css
div{
    width: 420px;
    height: 120px;
    margin: 20px 50px 30px 10px;
    padding: 30px;
    border: 10px solid #000;
    background-color: #ff8000;
    display: inline-block;
}
```

```html
    <h1>Titulo de nuestro sitio</h1>
    
    <a href="#">Enlace 1</a>
    <a href="#">Enlace 2</a>
    
    <div><p>Lorem Ipsum es simplemente el texto de relleno de las imprentas y archivos de texto. 
    Lorem Ipsum ha sido el texto de relleno estándar de las industrias desde el año 1500, cuando 
    un impresor (N. del T. persona que se dedica a la imprenta) desconocido usó una galería de 
    textos y los mezcló de tal manera que logró hacer un libro de textos especimen.
    </p></div>
    
    <div><p>No sólo sobrevivió 500 años, sino que tambien ingresó como texto de relleno en documentos 
    electrónicos, quedando esencialmente igual al original. Fue popularizado en los 60s con la 
    creación de las hojas "Letraset", las cuales contenian pasajes de Lorem Ipsum, 
    y más recientemente con software de autoedición, como por ejemplo Aldus PageMaker.</p></div>
```

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Como pueden ver en la imagen, los enlaces no se alinean verticalmente a la mitad con relación a los `divs`

La pregunta es porque pasa esto? Como es que podría solucionarlo??

Answer (score 1):

Basta con agregar `vertical-align: middle;` para que todo el contenido se centre verticalmente.

Ejecuta el snippet en pantalla completa para que veas el resultado.

```css
div{
    width: 420px;
    height: 120px;
    margin: 20px 50px 30px 10px;
    padding: 30px;
    border: 10px solid #000;
    background-color: #ff8000;
    display: inline-block;
    vertical-align: middle;
}
```

```html
<h1>Titulo de nuestro sitio</h1>
    
    <a href="#">Enlace 1</a>
    <a href="#">Enlace 2</a>
    
    <div><p>Lorem Ipsum es simplemente el texto de relleno de las imprentas y archivos de texto. 
    Lorem Ipsum ha sido el texto de relleno estándar de las industrias desde el año 1500, cuando 
    un impresor (N. del T. persona que se dedica a la imprenta) desconocido usó una galería de 
    textos y los mezcló de tal manera que logró hacer un libro de textos especimen.
    </p></div>
    
    <div><p>No sólo sobrevivió 500 años, sino que tambien ingresó como texto de relleno en documentos 
    electrónicos, quedando esencialmente igual al original. Fue popularizado en los 60s con la 
    creación de las hojas "Letraset", las cuales contenian pasajes de Lorem Ipsum, 
    y más recientemente con software de autoedición, como por ejemplo Aldus PageMaker.</p></div>
```